# Position a div containing iframe on right-hand side of screen?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I've succeeded in doing this a dozen different ways on desktop, but nothing seems to work on a mobile phone.

I've tried:
 - relative positions, absolute positions
 - float
 - various combinations of widths, margins and paddings
 - I even tried using a 1x2 table, where the first cell used width to push the 2nd cell over to the right

Can it even be done? Surely I've seen it done?

How do you position a div containing iframe on right-hand side of screen?

Comment: have you tried flexbox -  Make a container the width of the screen (100%, no margin, no padding, no parent containers, etc). then set the `flex-direction: row;` on the container as well as `justify-content: flex-end;`

Comment: @sao I've not been able to make flexbox work

Comment: i made an aggregator news page which does AJAX calls to RSS feeds. I used flexbox to sort the individual feeds, 25% width each, by row, so 4 per row. I am using a media query to make it appear one per row on mobile, im having some issues with it too. i feel like the more tools you use sometimes the more wildcards. for example, bootstrap, flexbox, media queries and browser compatibility..there are a lot of places for things to go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally managed something like it using tables.
Not only got on the right hand side, but also bottom right, which was a further goal.

```
<table id="table"><tr>
    <td id="cell1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="cell2">
        <div id="video">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/.......></iframe>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

---

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#table {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#cell1 {
    width:100%;
}
#video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vmax;
    height: 50vmax;
    right: -25vmax;
    padding-bottom: 20vmax;
}
#video iframe {
    border: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20vmax;
    padding-top: 0vmax;
    width: 20vmax;
    height: 20vmax;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try putting a wrapper around the iframe, then positioning the wrapper.

css

```
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Without seeing the complete html/css of both the page and the iframe, that's the best  recommendation I have.  The iframe itself can (and likely does) have it's own CSS, so keep that in mind too.

Here is a working example https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G86JSY65NPG2

The iframe contents didn't load properly on my mobile, but the iframe box is still there and positioned on the right.